# How to specify a specific queue to a WebJob listener

Tags: azure, azure-webjobs, azureservicebus, azure-servicebus-queues

This is one of those questions that I feel like I've solved in the past, but I don't seem to be able to atm.  I have a WebJob, and I simply want to listen for a message in a queue:

```
public static void ProcessQueueMessage(
        [QueueTrigger("myqueue")] string message,
        TextWriter log)
```

Running it locally, it runs, but when I add a message to `myqueue` nothing happens.  I'm pretty sure that the reason is that the queue trigger doesn't know where to look for my queue.  I feel like there should be a connection string property of QueueTrigger, but there isn't.

I've tried using the connection string from the `RootManageSharedAccessKey` on the service bus as the `AzureWebJobsStorage` value (also tried dashboard), but it doesn't like either connection string.  How can I point the web job at the right service bus?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`QueueTrigger` listens to a Storage Queue, not Service Bus queue. It's using `AzureWebJobsStorage` connection string by default.

If you need to process Service Bus messages, use `ServiceBusTrigger` attribute:

```cs
public static void ProcessQueueMessage(
    [ServiceBusTrigger("myqueue")] string message,
    TextWriter log)
```

The default connection string name is `AzureWebJobsServiceBus`. Otherwise you can set an alternative name of app setting for connection string via `Connection` property.

See [docs](https://github.com/Azure/azure-webjobs-sdk/wiki/Service-Bus) for further explanation.